# What cables can be connected to the Apple 30 Pin Connector?

Tags: iphone

What cables can be connected to the 30 Pin connector on Iphone 4S?

I mean to say; what output, input, audio, video, usb.... does it support.

Answer (score 1):

The layout of the connector can be found by a simple Google search:

- [Apple iPod, iPad and iPhone dock Connector Pinout](http://www.allpinouts.org/index.php/Apple_iPod,_iPad_and_iPhone_dock)
- [Dock Connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dock_Connector)

Comment: True, but to actually buy one and use it legally you have to sign away your first child and 20% of your list price.